# Spyder *paths* autocomplete not working

Tags: autocomplete, path, spyder

I've seen a lot of related questions on variables with Spyder. My problem, though, is with path autocompletion, as in

```
with open ('/Users/user_name/<TAB>
```

doing nothing. My local variables do get autocompleted;module functions as well. I'm running Python 3.5, Spyder 3.1.4 (from Anaconda). I have the following packages (that I think might be pertaining to the question) installed:

rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1
jedi                      0.10.2                   py35_2
numpydoc                  0.6.0                    py35_0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to run this in the Editor or the IPython console?

Comment: in the editor. In the IPython console it works fine. Update> today when I launch spyder from the terminal, I get this message:
"You have missing dependencies!

rope >=0.9.4: None (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message. [...] "

When I do conda list on the terminal, I see I have the rope I mentioned installed.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled the rope from conda ("conda uninstall rope") and installed with pip  ("pip install rope_py3k"). The warning is now gone, but path autocompletion in the editor is still not working.

Comment: Path completion in the Editor has never worked. If you want this feature, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we try to implement it in the future.